# Insert null into not null column with default FIREBIRD

Tags: sql, rdbms, firebird, firebird2.1

Inserting null into not null column with default is giving me a validation error instead of taking the default value. 
I don't want to make on before triggers to all of the tables. Is there any other way to do this?

Firebird 2.1.3

Answer (score 5):

The default value is used when you omit a field in the insert, not when you include the field with a null value.

Example:
Uses default for `Name`:

```
insert into SomeTable (Id) values (42)
```

Tries to insert `null` into `Name`:

```
insert into SomeTable (Id, Name) values (42, null)
```